# WCF Restful Services

Tags: wcf, rest

I'm developing wcf restful service using WCF 4.0. My question as below :

1. **The post method of the server side as below pic:**
   [image]
   [image]
2. **The code that made the post request to server as below pic:**
   [image]
3. **But when i debugged the service,i found the id property changed as below pic :**
   [image]

**I am confused why the value of ID property changed ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Restful Service Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169398/wcf-restful-service-post)

Comment: Please do not double-post questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case of the model id field is mismatching; you are passing `model.ID` and you are trying to read `model.Id.`
Change that `JObject` in the `GetModel()` method to be `model.Id` instead of `model.ID`.